# FirstGui cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to write a very simple GUI in java but I get one error that I really do not understand why it is happening.
The code is as bellow:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test extends JFrame {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        FirstGui gui = new FirstGui();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(200,200);
        gui.setvisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("chart-test");

     }

    }
```

and the error is on this line:

`FirstGui gui = new FirstGui();`

> Error:FirstGui cannot be resolved 
>        to a type

Comment: Do you even have a FirstGui class?

Comment: Is your `FirstGui.java` in the same directory as your `test.java`?

Comment: No I do not have FirstGui calss. I wrote this code from a tutorial on youtube and the guy didn't talk about having FirstGui calass and also he did not have any problem like this.

Comment: This is the link to the tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjOicuXEvwg

Comment: @zahra probably consider taking some basic Java tutorials before writing a GUI. You are missing some core concepts of Java and even of basic programming.

Comment: Oh I got what I am doing wrong. I should either change the class name to FirstGui or change the FirstGui inside the class to test. Thanks for you hints @DavidWallace Wallace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error:FirstGui cannot be resolved to a type

This means that the compiler cannot find any class called `FirstGui`

Since you named your class `test` (which, btw, should be called `Test` and put inside a package), you should probably try `test gui = new test();`

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test extends JFrame {
    public static void main (String args[])
        {
            test gui = new test();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gui.setSize(200,200);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("chart-test");

     }

    }
```

FYI:

- Everything related to Swing should be invoked on the AWT thread, so you should start your UI in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` call
- Don't extend if not needed. Here, no need to extend `JFrame`

Answer (score 1):

When you try to use a class, you need to be sure that it exists and it is reachable. In our case you need to create a class called `FirstGui`. I believe your `test` class should have been `FirstGui`.

Answer (score 0):

> public class test extends JFrame {

Double-check the video and make sure this line is the same as what the teacher types.